# C++ STL container ::clear ::swap

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std

What's the fastest way to "clear" a large STL container? In my application, I need to deal with large size `std::map`, e.g., 10000 elements.

I have tested the following 3 methods to clear a `std::map`.

- Create a new container every time I need it.
- Calling `map::clear()` method.
- Calling `map::swap()` method.

It seems that `::swap()` gives the best result. Can anyone explain why this is the case, please? Is it safe to say that using `map::swap()` method is the proper way to "clear" a std::map? Is it the same for other STL containers, e.g., `set`, `vector`, `list`, etc.

```
    m_timer_start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

//  test_map.clear();
    test_map.swap(test_map2);
    for (int i = 0; i< 30000; i++){
        test_map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(i, i));
    }    

//  std::map<int, int> test_map_new;
//  for (int i = 0; i< 30000; i++){
//      test_map_new.insert(std::pair<int, int>(i, i));
//  }     

    m_timer_end = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    std::cout << timer_diff(m_timer_start, m_timer_end).fractional_seconds() << std::endl; // microsecond
```

Comment: "Fastest" is almost always implementation-dependent.

Comment: How much of a difference was there between the three? If it's not much, I'd say clear would remain the most readable.

Comment: How are you using `std::swap` and how are you benchmarking this?

Comment: For a 30000 element std::map, using map::clear(), it takes about 15 millisecond, versus about 10 millisecond if uses map::swap(). Thanks.

Comment: `swap` in itself is certainly faster than `clear`, but it doesn't free any space. Are you sure you counted the destruction of the object you swapped with?

Comment: You should use larger test cases. A difference of 5 milliseconds is minimal.

Comment: We [you] need to more fully define what you mean by 'clear'.  Just telling the system the memory is ok to reuse? Setting each space to some null element? etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind response. I am new to C++ programming, I guess I am looking for a 'standard' way to do certain things. Thanks.

Comment: @2607 : The idiomatic way would be `std::map<int, int>().swap(test_map);`.

Comment: You're using a `map<int,int>`. See if you can use a sorted vector instead; that will certainly make `clear` faster.

Comment: @ildjarn: Well, the idiomatic way would be to use `.clear()`, swapping with an empty map is not idiomatic...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't properly testing the `swap` case. You need for the swap-to map to be destroyed in order to account for all of the time. Try one of these:

```
{ std::map<something, something_else> test_map2;
test_map.swap(test_map2);
} // test_map2 gets destroyed at the closing brace.
```

or

```
// temporary gets destroyed at the semi-colon
std::map<int, int>().swap(test_map);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking this because you're having a performance problem and you have identified that your program is spending too much time clearing your maps? If you haven't done this then just use map::clear() or create new local variables each time, whichever is most natural and direct for your program. The swap trick is an optimization and there's little point in wasting time optimizing unless you're certain you need to, based on experience.

If you have identified a performance issue then you've already got the tool to determine which of your methods best addresses it.

Comment: Good answer.  There is no "swap trick" though: see Rob's answer.

Comment: I think the "swap trick" optimization usually means swapping instead of assigning (copying) when the contents of the container the data is coming from is irrelevant afterwards. Though, this trick is mostly replaced by `std::move` in C++11.