# Faster method of clearing a boost::interprocess::map?

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, dictionary, stl

I have an application which uses a `boost::interprocess::map` in shared memory. The map contains a large number of elements (100k to 10M), and everything works pretty well, with one exception: the map has to be cleared periodically and this seems to take around 4 µs per element (so 40 seconds worst case), which is unacceptable for the application. It looks like `clear()` actually deletes each map element individually and rebalances the tree after each deletion, so it's horrendously inefficient when you have a large number of elements. Ideally `clear()` would just delete all the elements without any rebalancing - is there any way I can implement this kind of optimised `clear()` method myself ?

(Incidentally I've also tried `boost:interprocess:flat_map` - this has a much faster clear time, as might be expected (10x faster), but it's too slow for insert/delete operations.)

Note: an [earlier question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097772/c-stl-container-clear-swap) touched on a similar problem with smaller STL maps in normal (i.e. not shared) memory, but didn't really resolve the problem.

Comment: Can you just create a new empty map and then delete the old one on a low-priority background thread or something? Or is that too much of a pain with the shared memory coordination?

Comment: @ipmcc: thanks, yes, I plan to experiment with this, but as you note it's going to mess up my shared memory architecture if the map address can change periodically. Furthermore I have a horrible suspicion that deletion will be just as inefficient in that all the map elements will still be deleted individually, but I need to verify this.

Comment: @PaulR The map address doesn't need to change: just `swap` your maps. Then you can move the full map to a low priority thread as ipmcc suggested.

Comment: @syam: interesting idea - the only problem I see with this is that it might increase the total shared memory requirement considerably if I have two maps (one full map being cleared slowly and a new map being rapidly filled up). The map is currently over 1 GB for 10M elements.

Comment: @PaulR Indeed this can be a problem. Another idea: did you try the good old swap-with-temporary idiom, maybe the destruction of the map would be faster than calling `clear()`? `boost::interprocess::map<...>().swap(myMap);`

Comment: @syam: thanks - yes - I have a horrible suspicion that deletion will be just as inefficient in that all the map elements will still be deleted individually, but I am going to test this just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, there's no way around deleting all those nodes and that will be done in the worst possible way: fully random, thrashing your caches. Rebalancing the nodes is just the icing on the cake.

Comment: @PaulR: the elements unfortunately have to be deleted individually, unless they do not have destructors (but whether boost detects and optimizes this case is another matter); however there is indeed no reason to rebalance the tree each time, are you sure this occurs ?

Comment: Yes, I really need to profile this properly and see whether it's the rebalancing that's causing the problem - I'm assuming it is because the clear time of 4 µs is roughly the same as the insert/delete element time, but I need to check this properly.

Comment: BTW, do you have the compiler set for maximum optimization. The 'deleting' of the elements will be painfully slow in debug mode.

Comment: @Arun: good point, but yes, compiler optimisation is enabled (`-O3`).

Comment: One possible way to handle this is to slab allocate a large block of shared memory that will encompass the space needed for your interprocess::map.  Then replace the allocator used by the map to use space inside this slab allocation.  When clearing you can simply destroy the whole block and reallocate which should be much faster.  Granted that this approach is wickedly complicated.

Comment: Copy the boost::interprocess::map<> code and change the clear() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the Boost code, I am guessing you have either:

- Found a bug in the implementation of rbtree

or

- Coded using safe-mode or auto-unlink

From \boost_1_54_0\boost\intrusive\rbtree.hpp

```
   //! <b>Effects</b>: Erases all of the elements.
   //!
   //! <b>Complexity</b>: Linear to the number of elements on the container.
   //!   if it's a safe-mode or auto-unlink value_type. Constant time otherwise.
   //!
   //! <b>Throws</b>: Nothing.
   //!
   //! <b>Note</b>: Invalidates the iterators (but not the references)
   //!    to the erased elements. No destructors are called.
   void clear()
   {
      if(safemode_or_autounlink){
         this->clear_and_dispose(detail::null_disposer());
      }
      else{
         node_algorithms::init_header(this->priv_header_ptr());
         this->priv_size_traits().set_size(0);
      }
   }
```

The comment here clearly states that you can get constant time out of the implemented clear.  Paging through the boost code, my reading is that interprocess::map eventually uses this rbtree as the underlying data structure.  I did not notice anywhere safemode or auto-unlink were set, but I could have missed it.  If you have set one of these, I'd first see if I could live without it, and if so, your performance problems hopefully will go away.

If this is a bug in boost, you'll have to work around it.  I'd immediately report it using the contact information in the header:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// (C) Copyright Ion Gaztanaga  2006-2012
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
//    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
//          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// See http://www.boost.org/libs/intrusive for documentation.
//
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

A quick Google search appears to have contact details for Ion at:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=161440

Or by going to http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html

And then implement either Paul R or rileyberton's solution, depending on your level of performance needs.